# What would be the output of these SQL functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT EXTRACT(d from DATE_TRUNC('month', '2022-10-30'::DATE))
```

and

```
SELECT EXTRACT(month from '2022-10-30'::DATE + interval '5 days')
```

I thought it was going to be 30 for the first one because it says "D" before date trunc, but that is wrong.

For the second one, I am confused and I wasn't able to find any helpful tips on the internet nor was my book helpful . I am not understanding how +interval 5 days can affect the month.

If you could help me with this, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't guess, don't ask, don't think, just try out.

Comment: For the second one, inspect the result of `'2022-10-30'::DATE + interval '5 days'` and you will see how that will affect the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query will return 1 as you are using DATE_TRUNC with field 'month' and datepart is DATE so it will return

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', '2022-10-30'::DATE)
```

will return **2022-10-01T00:00:00Z** and when you extract the d then it will return **1**.

For the second case when you are adding 5 days to the date then the date is changing to **2022-11-04T00:00:00Z**  hence the month is changing to **11** instead of **10** hence the result will be **11**.